# How to retrive my markers from Firestore to Google Map?

Tags: firebase, google-maps, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm stuck since the big update on Firebase. I can't manage to show my markers from Firestore to Google Maps.

Before, it worked. I don't understand what is wrong with my code.

I have this error when I run my code:

```
E/flutter ( 8450): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'data'
E/flutter ( 8450): Receiver: Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':.
E/flutter ( 8450): Tried calling: data()
E/flutter ( 8450): Found: data() => Map<String, dynamic>
```

Code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';

class NewMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewMapState createState() => _NewMapState();
}

class _NewMapState extends State<NewMap> {
  GoogleMapController _controller;

  Position position;

  Widget _child;

  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
  BitmapDescriptor pinLocationIcon;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _child = SpinKitRipple(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return DecoratedBox(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: index.isEven ? Colors.grey : Color(0xffffb838),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    getCurrentLocation();
    populateClients();
    setCustomMapPin();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getCurrentLocation() async {
    Position res = await getCurrentPosition();
    setState(() {
      position = res;
      _child = mapWidget();
    });
  }

  populateClients() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("AllTombs").get().then((docs) {
      if (docs.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < docs.docs.length; ++i) {
          initMarker(docs.docs[i].data, docs.docs[i].id);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  void initMarker(tomb, tombId) {
    var markerIdVal = tombId;
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);

    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      position: LatLng(
          tomb.data()['location'].latitude, tomb.data()['location'].latitude),
      icon: pinLocationIcon,
    );
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
  }

  void setCustomMapPin() async {
    pinLocationIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5), 'assets/icon/pin.png');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Color(0xffffb838)),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: _child,
    );
  }

  Widget mapWidget() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
              zoom: 10,
            ),
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              _controller = controller;
            },
            compassEnabled: true,
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values)),
        SizedBox(
          height: 26,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the new version you need to use `data()`:

```
  populateClients() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("AllTombs").get().then((docs) {
      if (docs.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < docs.docs.length; ++i) {
          initMarker(docs.docs[i].data(), docs.docs[i].id);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Peter Habbad ! it's working :) Do you know how to go to detail page when i click to the infoWindow ?

Comment: @sarahpougnaud what `infoWindow`? I still haven't used google-maps so not sure.. But it must probably be just using the Navigator and sending data to the other page

Comment: The infowindow it's the pop up that open when you click on your location pin. But i'm really bad to send data to others pages. How do you manage to in my case ?